# What is BuildOptions in sequelize

Tags: typescript, express, sequelize.js

I have read through sequelize documentation and googled this question. Couldn't find any explanation.  Why is BuildOptions needed and how it affects the model created?

```
import { Sequelize, Model, DataTypes, BuildOptions } from 'sequelize';
// We need to declare an interface for our model that is basically what our class would be
interface MyModel extends Model {
  readonly id: number;
}

// Need to declare the static model so `findOne` etc. use correct types.
type MyModelStatic = typeof Model & {
  new (values?: object, options?: BuildOptions): MyModel;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After searching the node_modules/sequelize folder for `BuildOptions`, this turns up on lines 630-651 in node_modules/sequelize/types/lib/model.d.ts in version `6.6.5` of sequelize.

```
/**  
  * Options for Model.build method                                                                       
  */  
 export interface BuildOptions {
   /**
    * If set to true, values will ignore field and virtual setters.
    */                      
   raw?: boolean;
                                                                          
   /**
    * Is this record new
    */
   isNewRecord?: boolean;
  
   /**
    * An array of include options. A single option is also supported - Used to build prefetched/included model instances. See `set`
    * 
    * TODO: See set                 
    */
   include?: Includeable | Includeable[];
}
```

This appears to be the same interface used when calling the `Model.build` method to construct a new model instance in `sequelize`, before saving it to the database.  Here's a link to the [api reference](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-build), where it's the second argument to the `build` method.  Also, here are the [relevant pages](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-instances.html#creating-an-instance) in the manual.

This would pretty much have to be the same interface mentioned in the question, since it's the only definition for `BuildOptions` that appears in the node_modules/sequelize folder.

As a sidenote, although it's mentioned in [version 5 of the manual](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/typescript.html) (see the code in original question), it's absent from the same pages in the docs in [version 6](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html).